# Changing a label's text by the FOR attribute

Tags: javascript

I would like to set the text of the label. Unfortunately the number 36 will change on each page refresh.

```
<label for="rn_TextInput_36_Incident.CustomFields.c.other_action_taken" id="rn_TextInput_36_Label" class="rn_Label">TEXT HERE</label>
<input type="text" id="rn_TextInput_36_Incident.CustomFields.c.other_action_taken" name="Incident.CustomFields.c.other_action_taken" class="rn_Text" maxlength="50" required="">
```

I can get the ID by using:

```
var id = document.getElementsByName('Incident.CustomFields.c.other_action_taken')[0].getAttribute('id');
```

How can I then use this to set the label text i.e. target the label by the value of the `for` attribute in JavaScript - not jQuery

So as mentioned, the number will change each time so I can't use the ID value of `rn_TextInput_36_Label` that the label currently has

Comment: The `for` attribute will also change, so we can't use it!

Comment: how about: document.querySelector('[for="rn_TextInput_36_Incident.CustomFields.c.other_action_taken"]').innerText = 'new text'?

Comment: I can get the ID of the input which is the same as the for value - is there nothing we can do around this?

Comment: It's unclear what your objective is?

Comment: Is it @zer00ne as others seem to have understood. I need to change label text based on the for attribute

Comment: <label for='X'>X</label> ?

Comment: @pee2pee If your #IDs change then gather every input into an array and change things accordingly. See my answer, it doesn't matter what the #ID is or how many you have.

Comment: @zer00ne: It does matter if the OP doesn't want to operate on any arbitrary `label`, which is very obviously the case here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var id = document.getElementsByName('Incident.CustomFields.c.other_action_taken')[0].getAttribute('id');
document.querySelector("label[for='"+id+"']").innerText = 'new text';
```

It gets the ID and then uses querySelector to get the related label and sets the innertext

Answer (score 0):

Your element has the class `rn_Label`, so you can select by that.

```
var el = documment.querySelector(".rn_Label");
```

If you need to get more specific, you can include the tag name and part of the `for` attribute.

```
var el = documment.querySelector("label.rn_Label[for^=rn_TextInput_][for$=_Incident.CustomFields.c.other_action_taken]");
```

So this last selector selects the first element that:

- has tag name `label`
- has class name `rn_Label`
- has a `for` attribute that starts with `rn_TextInput_`
- has a `for` attribute that ends with `_Incident.CustomFields.c.other_action_taken`

And of course you can use `querySelectorAll` to select all elements on the page that meet that criteria.

Comment: So you are assuming that OP needs only this specific label/input  pair fixed and I assume that there are more. The results are the same until OP says otherwise.

Comment: @zer00ne: I'm not assuming. That's the whole point of the question, which you seem to be struggling to understand. So fine if you want to downvote me, but seriously...

Comment: I updated my answer due to your constant nagging. The whole point of the question isn't clear. BTW didn't downvote you and you may downvote me as you please I have plenty of points.

Comment: @zer00ne: First, yes you did down vote. Second, I didn't down vote you, because I can't, because I haven't registered my account. Third, the entire point is literally about selecting a specific element, yet your first comment under the OP shows you couldn't see what is remarkably clear. Lastly, It isn't nagging. I'm either pointing out your errors or responding to your comments to help you understand really basic stuff. Now I have to go correct your answer again...

Comment: "I need to change label text based on the for attribute" coincides with "t gets the ID and then uses querySelector to get the related label and sets the innertext"

Comment: "I need to change label text based on the for attribute" coincides with "t gets the ID and then uses querySelector to get the related label and sets the innertext"

Comment: My original answer does the first sentence just that without any JS. The second sentence is addressed by my updates.

Comment: "I need to change label text based on the for attribute" `::before content:attr(for)`  gets the ID and then uses querySelector to get the related label and sets the innertext" See Demo 1 and 2

Comment: @zer00ne: Sorry, can't hold your hand anymore. Hope you learn how to accept being wrong, especially when the OP explicitly tells you you're wrong.

Comment: "I need to change label text based on the for attribute" coincides with "t gets the ID and then uses querySelector to get the related label and sets the innertext"

Comment: I'd love to be wrong , you can prove me wrong by explaining this: "I need to change label text based on the for attribute" coincides with "it gets the ID and then uses querySelector to get the related label and sets the innertext"

Comment: @zer00ne: LOL, I remember you now... you're the one who couldn't figure out the same old async problem that another user was asking about. You kept insisting that `.map()` would make some kind of difference. Now I see the real problem here.

Comment: I can own up to that one, I realized that currying would work and map() was not necessary. Now explain to me this: "I need to change label text based on the for attribute" coincides with "it gets the ID and then uses querySelector to get the related label and sets the innertext" If you try to steer this in any other direction you are just an argumentative person I understand that perfectly.

Comment: I've given multiple explanations, the OP told you your answer is not what they want, the OP told you that other commenters understood when you didn't. If that doesn't get you there... well... I'm afraid I've put things as gently as I can. Anything more will just hurt your feelings.

Comment: I see you are that type and nothing you could say could hurt my feelings. You are not mature enough to admit that you overstepped. You are dodging a direct question.

Comment: @zer00ne: Sorry buddy, but I've held your hand with simple explanations. If that makes me "that type", then yeah, I'm good with that.

Comment: I will admit that my first demo may not be the best solution if in fact OP has one label to change so I updated. That you have enlightened me. But the rest of your arguments are pure dribble. You have an opinion on everything and how I don't understand yet you become increasingly belligerent  when I confront you with this:"I need to change label text based on the for attribute" coincides with "t gets the ID and then uses querySelector to get the related label and sets the innertext"

Comment: @zer00ne: I like dribble; keeps my chin moist. I've already answered you multiple times on this page. Go ahead and study that information, and then study up on the definition of "belligerent".

Comment: You did not answer: "I need to change label text based on the for attribute" coincides with "t gets the ID and then uses querySelector to get the related label and sets the innertext" How do I not understand this? And other answers and comments are to the contrary of what I understand and the validity of my answer?

Comment: @zer00ne: You need to understand that feeling right isn't the same as being right and being corrected isn't inherently offensive. It's only taken as an offense by those who are upset by it. The OP told you that  you didn't understand the question, but the others did. But I guess you still know better? Weird...

Comment: That was hours ago. I have updated my answer twice since then. It's obvious that you cannot see when you are at fault. I have acquessed several times. *" LOL, I remember you now... you're the one who couldn't figure out the same old async problem that another user was asking about. You kept insisting that .map() would make some kind of difference. Now I see the real problem here. "* that's petty and belligerent. I even owned up to it. *"I need to change label text based on the for attribute" "it gets the ID and then uses querySelector to get the related label and sets the innertext"*

Comment: My comment was dismissive and mildly mocking in response to your repeatedly asking the same questions that I already addressed. Your answer's one update was technically valid but had the fragility and oddity that I explained.

Answer (score 0):

you can work same as this code:

```
    var input = document.getElementsByName('Incident.CustomFields.c.other_action_taken')[0];
if(input.labels.length > 0) {
    var labelID = input.labels[0].id;
    document.getElementById(labelID ).innerHTML = 'New Text for this lable';
}
else {
     alert('there is no label for this input');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/SETha/75/